# When to use InvalidOperationException or NotSupportedException?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, invalidoperationexception, notsupportedexception

I am implementing a custom collection implementation that can either be readonly or non-readonly; that is, all the methods that change the collection call a function that is the moral equivalent of:

```
private void ThrowIfReadOnly() {
    if (this.isReadOnly)
       throw new SomeException("Cannot modify a readonly collection.");
}
```

I am not sure which of `NotSupportedException` or `InvalidOperationException` I should use in that case.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The MSDN only has one bit of guidance on this precise topic, on [`NotSupportedException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notsupportedexception.aspx):

> For scenarios where it is sometimes possible for the object to perform the requested operation, and the object state determines whether the operation can be performed, see [`InvalidOperationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx).

What follows is purely my own interpretation of the rule:

- If the object's state can change so that the operation can become invalid / valid during the object's lifetime, then `InvalidOperationException` should be used.
- If the operation is always invalid / valid during the whole object's lifetime, then `NotSupportedException` should be used.
- In that case, "lifetime" means "the whole time that anyone can get a reference to the object" - that is, even after a `Dispose()` call that often makes most other instance methods unusable;

  - As pointed out by Martin Liversage, in the case of an object having been disposed, the more specific `ObjectDisposedException` type should be used. (That is still a subtype of `InvalidOperationException`).

The practical application of these rules in that case would be as follows:

- If `isReadOnly` can only be set at the time when the object is created (e.g. a constructor argument), and never at any other time, then `NotSupportedException` should be used.
- If `isReadOnly` can change during the lifetime of the object, then `InvalidOperationException` should be used.

  - However, the point of `InvalidOperationException` vs `NotSupportedException` is actually moot in the case of implementing a collection - given the description of [`IsReadOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cfatk9t.aspx) on MSDN, the only permitted behavior for `IsReadOnly` is that its value never changes after the collection is initialized. Meaning that a collection instance can either be modifiable or read-only - but it should choose one at initialization and stick with it for the rest of its lifetime.

Comment: Calling a method on a disposed object should throw `ObjectDisposedException` instead of `InvalidOperationException` even though it is an invalid operation.

Comment: @Martin: Oh, nice one! I did not know about `ObjectDisposedException` at all. (And as `ObjectDisposedException` is a subtype of `InvalidOperationException`, it ties in nicely with being a particular case of `InvalidOperationException`)