# Should I use ArgumentException or InvalidEnumArgumentException for an Enum extension method?

Tags: c#

I have seen suggestions for both but would like to confirm that this is the best way to do this:

```
public enum MO
{
   Learn = 0,
   Practice = 1,
   Quiz = 2
}

public static partial class Extensions
{
   public static MO ToMode(this string mode)
   {
      switch (mode)
      {
         case "Learn": return MO.Learn;
         case "Practice": return MO.Practice;
         case "Quiz": return MO.Quiz;
         default: throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("Unhandled value: " + mode.ToString());
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it can be `NotSupportedException`... maybe answer also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669805/when-to-use-invalidoperationexception-or-notsupportedexception

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use `ArgumentException` in this case. The documentation for `InvalidEnumArgumentException` [states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.invalidenumargumentexception?view=netframework-4.8):

> This exception is thrown if you pass an invalid enumeration value to a method or when setting a property.

which is not what you're doing here. You're passing a string, not an enumeration. The description for `ArgumentException` [looks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentexception?view=netframework-4.8) more appropriate:

> The exception that is thrown when one of the arguments provided to a method is not valid.

Answer (score 3):

I'd be inclined to let the framework decide. Here's the way the framework does it:

```
public static partial class Extensions
{
    public static MO ToMode(this string mode) => (MO)Enum.Parse(typeof(MO), mode);
}
```

Now that throws an `ArgumentException` if you pass an invalid string.

---

Alternatively, you could implement `TryParseMode` to avoid exceptions entirely:

```
public static partial class Extensions
{
    private static Dictionary<string, MO> _lookup =
        Enum
            .GetNames(typeof(MO))
            .ToDictionary(n => n, n => n.ToMode());

    public static bool TryParseMode(this string mode, out MO value)
    {
        var found = _lookup.ContainsKey(mode);
        value = found ? _lookup[mode] : default(MO);
        return found;
    }

    public static MO ToMode(this string mode) => (MO)Enum.Parse(typeof(MO), mode);
}
```

You'd use that like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Learn".TryParseMode(out MO m1));
Console.WriteLine("LearnX".TryParseMode(out MO m2));
```

...which returns:

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't throw at all. Stay pure.

```
   public static (bool, MO) ToMode(this string mode)
   {
      switch (mode)
      {
         case "Learn": return (true, MO.Learn);
         case "Practice": return (true, MO.Practice);
         case "Quiz": return (true, MO.Quiz);
         default: return (false, default);
      }
    }
```

...let your caller to check the flag and decide what to do.

Other way to do that is to have `MO.Unset` option serving as default "not recognized" label. Then you simply return your `MO.Unset` whenever input argument is unexpected.

Keep your code pure, young jedi.

P.S. It is always good practice to have a default value on the `enum` even if you won't use it in a way I've recommended: `enum`'s are value type and thus always have non-null `default` value; in case you won't provide one, it is quite possible to mess up.

Comment: I'm not sure why the down vote.  Even Microsoft [Enum Design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/enum) documentation states *DO provide a value of zero on simple enums.

Consider calling the value something like "None." If such a value is not appropriate for this particular enum, the most common default value for the enum should be assigned the underlying value of zero.* which is what it appears you are trying to convey.

Comment: Another possibility is to make the return type `MO?` and return `null` if an error occurs. This also has the advantage that you could use the null-coalescing operator easily control what should happen if null is returned.

Comment: Throwing exceptions is not a bad thing by itself. If done right, such as in this case, it's a legitimate design.